# How Can I open an html file on a local server by using python (python -m http.server)?

Tags: html, python-3.x, localserver

When I try to run the following code in the directory where my index.html file is saved:

```
python -m http.server 8888
```

I get this error: 
*This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at http://0.0.0.0:8888/index.html might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID*
How can I solve this issue?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.0.0.0 is not a routable address.  You put 0.0.0.0 on the command line sometimes to let the server know to listen on any interface. But to route to yourself, you must use the IP address 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score -1):

In Python3 I had the above issue on the computer where I was seconded to a company and couldn't bring my own equipment to.
"Simply" changing 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1 didn't do the trick for me on the locked computer, so the issue was resolved by: pyCharm's terminal:

```
python -m http.server 9000 --directory 'C:\Users\PathToYourHTMLFile\' --bind 127.0.0.1
```

Then in the webbrowser type:

```
127.0.0.1:9000/PathToYourHTMLFileFromCurrentFolder
```

Comment: Somebody gave a thumbs down without even explaining, while the above works on a restricted system without accessing hacks. There is no reason to give a vote down since I have explained why it doesn't worked and shared what does. The worst of all: I did show the bind while the "solution answer didn't". Changing 127.0.0.1 in the browser didn't work for me without the bind and that is new information for the next one to come. People like you are the problem of StackOverflow, shoo.